# How can rust safely drop a cpp array through FFI?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a array `T*` which is created like the following

```
T* array = new T[len];
// Some initialization codes
```

We know we can delete the array like

```
delete [] array;
```

However, I am writing a Rust FFI program with C++. I have sent this `array` pointer to the Rust part of my code, and I want to delete the code now.

So I can implement a function `ffi_delete_array_of_T` on the C++ part, and the Rust part code will call the function through FFI, attached with the argument `array`.

```
void ffi_delete_array_of_T(void * arr) {
    delete [] reinterpret_cast<T *>(arr);
}
```

However, I already have a function which can delete single element of `T`.

```
void ffi_delete_pointer_of_T(void * arr) {
    delete reinterpret_cast<T *>(arr);
}
```

These two functions are so similar that I wonder if I can combined them into one, so I don't need to write two copy.

```
void ffi_delete_whatever_of_T(void * arr, bool is_array) {
    if (is_array)
        delete [] reinterpret_cast<T *>(arr);
    else
        delete reinterpret_cast<T *>(arr);
}
```

However, I still think the above codes redundant. I wonder if I only give `ffi_delete_pointer_of_T`, is it possible the Rust do some magic, and have `ffi_delete_array_of_T` for me?

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible. C++ can `delete []` a array without hint of length, because it has already stored the length of `array` somewhere when `array` is allocated. However, the Rust part don't know the actual length of this `array`.

However, I still wonder if there are some other ways to do that?

Comment: I feel the first version with 2 functions for 2 different tasks is the most "Rusty".

Comment: Your second version is just plain weird and ill-advised. Having specialized functions, akin to `delete` vs. `delete[]`, is far more conventional.

Comment: Is there any way of exposing allocator and deallocator pairs of functions, regardless of if the deallocators are, in many cases, internally the same? It's a lot better to think in terms of `alloc_X()` and `free_X()` than it is in terms of `alloc_X()` and then remembering which deallocator to use. Make it *stupidly* obvious what the correct pairing is, because we all have stupid days.

Comment: @tadman You also need to run the destructor.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The FFI interface should perform that operation in the `free` side of things. It's C++ exposed with C naming conventions, but it's still C++.